# WM_COPYDATA with array vs vector

Tags: c++, arrays, winapi, vector, ipc

I'm trying to achieve inter-process communication via WM_COPYDATA messages. lpData member of COPYDATASTRUCT can not contain pointers. My problem is, what is the difference between char arrays and other arrays or vectors.

When I use char array like here, it sends messages succesfully.

```
typedef struct tagMYSTRUCT {
wchar_t x[40] = {0};
} MYSTRUCT, *PMYSTRUCT;
```

But when I use a vector, receiving application can not get it.

```
typedef struct tagOTHERSTRUCT {
    wchar_t one[40] = { 0 };
    wchar_t two[20] = { 0 };
    wchar_t three[20] = { 0 };
    wchar_t four[4] = { 0 };
    wchar_t five[3] = { 0 };
} OTHERSTRUCT, *POTHERSTRUCT;

typedef struct tagMYSTRUCT2 {
    std::vector<OTHERSTRUCT> y;
} MYSTRUCT2, *PMYSTRUCT2;
```

I have an externed global vector 'gOtherStructList'. In the various parts of the program, this global variable is filled. For example,

```
DWORD WINAPI foo(LPCTSTR lpchText) {
    ...
    if (sizeof(lpchText[0]) == 2) {
        wcscpy(gOtherStructList[0].one, lpchText);
    }

    ...
}
```

Then, when I'm sending this global list, I'm copying it into MYSTRUCT2 variable  (for unrelated reasons) with wcscpy() for every wchar_t of every element.

This is how I send to receiver app:

```
MYSTRUCT2 my_struct;    //my_struct.y is a vector

// Filled my_struct.y here with wcscpy()

COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
cds.dwData = MY_CASE;
cds.cbData = sizeof(OTHERSTRUCT) *  my_struct.y.size();
cds.lpData = &my_struct;

SendMessage(gDataReceiver, WM_COPYDATA, NULL, (LPARAM)&cds);
```

If it makes difference, receiving application uses these messages like:

```
case WM_COPYDATA:
{
    PCOPYDATASTRUCT pcopydata = (PCOPYDATASTRUCT)lParam;

    switch (pcopydata->dwData) {

    case MY_CASE:

        // When I code this, it works
        PMYSTRUCT p = (PMYSTRUCT)(pcopydata->lpData);
        wcscpy(mylocalvar, p->x); // for char array

        ...
        // But, this doesn't work.

        std::cout << "New message received" << std::endl;    // this gets printed, then program crashes.

        PMYSTRUCT2 p = (PMYSTRUCT2)(pcopydata->lpData);
        OTHERSTRUCT mylocallist[100],
        wcscpy(mylocallist[0].one, p->y[0].one);
}
```

I understand why we can't use pointers for WM_COPYDATA. What I don't understand is, what is the difference of these examples. Why we can use char arrays but not vectors?

**Edit:** *Edited my question, based on informative comments.*

Thanks

Comment: [WM_COPYDATA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649011.aspx) can marshal a single chunk of memory across process boundaries. If you need to communicate structured data, you'll need to serialize it, and deserialize it in the receiving process. I'm guessing that `OTHERSTRUCT` contains pointers, either directly or indirectly. Pointers are only valid in the process where they originate from.

Comment: OTHERSTRUCT has 5 wchar_t arrays. Nothing more. But when i try to copy them, it gives error unlike the first example.

Comment: You have to show the declaration of `OTHERSTRUCT`

Comment: Show the declaration of `OTHERSTRUCT` and the code that fills in `MYSTRUCT2` on the sending side. Are those wchar_t arrays nul-terminated?

Comment: Unless I'm blind, there's nothing wrong with the part of the code just posted (including the structure definition).  Perhaps there's a problem with the code that is sending the message?  (Best guess: you're calculating the size incorrectly.)

Comment: I have edited and added OTHERSRUCT. Also I tried to explain how it's filled.

Comment: I think we need to see the code that calls PostMessage / SendMessage.

Comment: And I'm calculating the size with, sizeof(OTHERSTRUCT) * length_of_array

Comment: You can't send a vector, or any other non-POD class object, via WM_COPYDATA.  For one thing, the layout in memory isn't defined by the standard, and may contain process-specific content such as a vtable pointer.  For another, a vector is implemented using pointers, which are only valid in the original process.  An array is fine, that's POD.  A vector isn't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are POD types in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c)

Comment: I tried to convert it to array but it crashed again. That's why I tought it won't make any difference if it's an array or a vector. Maybe I made another unrelated mistake when coding that, not sure now. I will try that again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::vector` is internally implemented using pointers, so you cannot send that, but you can send its data, as it is guaranteed to be continuous in memory, and your internal struct is a POD.

You get the necessary pointer with `std::vector::data()`:

```
cds.cbData = sizeof(OTHERSTRUCT) *  my_struct.y.size();
cds.lpData = my_struct.y.data();
```

NOTE: VC++ somewhat lacks in C++ support, so this `data()` is not available in VS2010 or before. You can replace it, if needed with:

```
cds.lpData = &my_struct.y[0];
```

Just be sure that the vector is not empty.

And in the receiving side:

```
OTHERSTRUCT *begin = static_cast<OTHERSTRUCT*>(pcopydata->lpData);
OTHERSTRUCT *end = begin + pcopydata->cbData / sizeof(OTHERSTRUCT);
//copy the data into a vector, or treat them directly
std::vector<OTHERSTRUCT> recvData(begin, end);
```

Personally I find the `MYSTRUCT2` useless and a bit misleading.

Comment: Thanks for sample code. Now it works. One more question: What is the best approach to copy incoming data into an already existing vector? I created a temporary vector with a constructor as in your code, then used assignment operator: `gList = recvData;` How can we do it without creating temporary vector?

Comment: @ilkerpyci: If you use C++11 or later, then `std::vector` is moveable, so `gList = std::vector(begin, end)` just works (or `gList = std::move(recvData)` if you prefer a named variable to a temporary). If you are stuck with pre C++11 or want to avoid moves, you can write `gList.clear(); gList.append(gList.end(), begin, end);`.

Answer (score 2):

`MYSTRUCT` and `OTHERSTRUCT` contain all of their data inside of themselves, there are no pointers to outside memory, so they can be transmitted as-is as single memory blocks via `WM_COPYDATA`.

`MYSTRUCT2`, on the other hand, contains a `std::vector` of `OTHERSTRUCT` elements.  Only the `vector` itself resides inside of `MYSTRUCT2` itself. The   `vector` internally contains a pointer (amongst other things) to a `OTHERSTRUCT` array located elsewhere in memory.  Because of this, `MYSTRUCT2` cannot be transmitted as-is as a single memory block via `WM_COPYDATA`, it needs to be serialized into a flat data block for sending, and then deserialized when received, eg:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct tagMYCDSDATA {
    int numItems;
    OTHERSTRUCT items[1];
} MYCDSDATA, *PMYCDSDATA;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

```
MYSTRUCT2 my_struct;
// Fill my_struct.y as needed...

int count = my_struct.y.size();    
std::vector<BYTE> buffer(sizeof(int) + (sizeof(OTHERSTRUCT) * count));
PMYCDSDATA cdsdata = reinterpret_cast<PMYCDSDATA>(&buffer[0]);
//or, if using C++11: PMYCDSDATA cdsdata = reinterpret_cast<PMYCDSDATA>(buffer.data());

data->numItems = count;
std::copy(my_struct.y.begin(), my_struct.y.end(), data->items);

COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
cds.dwData = MY_CASE;
cds.cbData = buffer.size();
cds.lpData = cdsdata;

SendMessage(gDataReceiver, WM_COPYDATA, NULL, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&cds));
```

```
case WM_COPYDATA:
{
    PCOPYDATASTRUCT pcopydata = reinterpret_cast<PCOPYDATASTRUCT>(lParam);
    if (pcopydata->dwData == MY_CASE)
    {
        std::cout << "New message received" << std::endl;

        PMYCDSDATA p = static_cast<PMYCDSDATA>(pcopydata->lpData);
        for(int i = 0; i < p->numItems; ++i)
        {
            // use p->item[i].one, etc as needed...
        }

        return 0;
    }

    break;
}
```